# How does the critical Angle of attack changes with Increasing Reynolds Number?

Tags: aerodynamics, angle-of-attack, reynolds-number

I am simulating NACA 2415 Airfoil for different Reynolds Number i.e. 2 million,3 million and 4 million on ANSYS Fluent. The difference between the critical Angle of attack is quite vast. For the 4 million Re number, I am getting a critical Angle of attack close to 46 degrees which seems to be very weird and looks incorrect to me. 
Any explaination of how different the critical Angle of attacks would be for the above mentioned Reynolds Number?

Comment: There are two different questions in here: CFD stall prediction and Reynolds number effect. What turbulence model are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using k omega sst. I got a good result for Reynolds number of 3 million. I am using a unstructured mesh for it. But for 4 million and Reynolds number differing by a million atleast, I am getting poor results when it comes to critical angle of attack

Comment: Try to improve your boundary layer mesh. As you already pointed out, 46 deg stall AOA is certainly not right. I'm surprised it even converged. Reynolds number does delay flow separation, but not nearly to that extent.